# Resources for learning how to design good API wrappers in ruby

Tags: ruby, api, wrapper, dsl

I'd like to learn how to design good API wrappers in ruby. I'm looking for:

- blog articles
- tutorials
- best code and library to learn from the code directly (well commented and designed)
- books

... and also,

what are some of your favorite API wrappers and what makes them special?

Any source is welcome Thanks in advance

UPDATE jun 29 2011

[Building a Platform API on Rails](https://blog.codepath.com/2011/06/27/building-a-platform-api-on-rails/)

UPDATE: 13/06/2011

have a look at great post on how to develop an an API wrapper/interface client:
 - http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/56

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chapter 2 of Ruby Best Practices might be helpful. [You can read it for free here](http://github.com/sandal/rbp-book/raw/gh-pages/pdfs/ch02.pdf).

Comment: ... you meant Chapter 2: "Designing Beautiful APIs"  :-)

Comment: ... and here it is a good article http://wynnnetherland.com/blog/what-makes-a-good-api-wrapper

Comment: ... an old article, but still get the point to build client wrappers http://adam.heroku.com/past/2008/8/8/ruby_libs_for_making_web/

Comment: monster_mash: this is great. Provides a fun interface to quickly build API libraries using Typhoeus: https://github.com/dbalatero/monster_mash

Comment: ... net and clean even raw, a simple wrapper for "whoisxmlapi" based on Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)) — Read more: https://github.com/ahlatimer/Whois-API-Ruby-Wrapper/blob/master/whois_api_wrapper.rb

Comment: precious client performance comparison: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/blob/master/benchmarks/clients.rb

Comment: ... another HTTP Request Performance comparison to develop even faster API wrappers: http://toevolve.org/2011/04/03/http-request-performance.html ( on github - https://github.com/threez/test-http-clients )

Comment: CORS API with OAuth2 authentication using Rails and AngularJS looks great http://nils-blum-oeste.net/cors-api-with-oauth2-authentication-using-rails-and-angularjs/#.US93MX0u7Lc

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. Is it maybe available somewhere else? Are there any good, up-to-date ressources?

Comment: Wrapping Your API In A Custom Ruby Gem  https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/wrapping-your-api-in-a-ruby-gem

Answer (score 9):

since testing is one part of a good API wrapper I recommend this for a start on the topic.

[Writing an API Wrapper in Ruby with TDD](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/writing-an-api-wrapper-in-ruby-with-tdd/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Instagram Ruby Client](https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem). 
It should give you a fair idea on how to write modular third party API wrappers in Ruby.